# Declaration of passes(string $attribute, $value): bool must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule::passes($attribute, $value)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have created a custom validation rule

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Exception;

class ValidFoo implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes(string $attribute, $value): bool
    {
        if (!$foo) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message(): string
    {
        return 'The foo you \'ve provided is not valid.';
    }
}
```

However when I try to submit the form I get this error

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Declaration of App\Rules\ValidFoo::passes(string $attribute, $value): bool must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule::passes($attribute, $value)
```

This is Laravel's Rule interface

```
namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Validation;

interface Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value);

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Exception;

class ValidFoo implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (!$foo) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message(): string
    {
        return 'The foo you \'ve provided is not valid.';
    }
}
```

This is a corrected class. Error occurse because you use type hit, but interface does not used type hint